# Swift NSManagedObjects do not support mutableSetValueForKey

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmutablearray, nsmanagedobject

I am practicing my tute task on Swift CoreData. This is a reminder app, I have these entities in the core data file:

And the error is in my viewDidLoad() function:

```
var reminderList: NSMutableArray

//In viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //fetchRequest code blocks

    self.reminderList = NSMutableArray(array: (currentReminders?.members?.allObjects) as! [Reminder])
```

I got this error message: `'NSManagedObjects of entity 'ReminderList' do not support -mutableSetValueForKey: for the property 'members''` and the app crashed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is because of a mistake in setting relationship between entities in the CoreData. Just check to see if the constraints are set properly for To-One/Many.